# SignalR client to client works fine server to client fails

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignaLR 2.x server and it's client implementations

when I send a message client-to-client everything works fine, but when I send a message server-to-client, message never fires.

This is my hub

```
[HubName("Notifications")]
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

    public void SendMessage(string userId, string message)
    {
        // Send a message to the specified user
        Clients.User(userId).ReceiveMessage(message);
    }


    public void ProcesarNotificacion(MessageType messageType, string messageInfo)
    {
        IMessageInfo info = Zipper.FromZJson<MessageInfoBase>(messageInfo);
        if (info.MessageTarget.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace())
            Clients.All.ProcesarNotificacion(messageType, messageInfo);
        else
            Clients.User(info.MessageTarget.ToLower().Trim()).ProcesarNotificacion(messageType, messageInfo);
    }
}
```

And This is my try to send message server-to-client

```
string messageInfo = "something";
IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
context.Clients.All.ProcesarNotificacion(MessageType.PrintInvoice, messageInfo);
```

I was figthing a lot of time and ended up implementing a client into the server, i sounds extrange but it works.

Questions:

**Why my fisrt way does not work?**

**It's a bad approach the second implementation?**

**NOTE:** Remember that client-to-client works pretty well then is not about my hub or my setup.